# What is mobiquo.php?

Tags: php, webserver

Recently, I've been receiving tons of entries for "/mobiquo/mobiquo.php" in my server logs. However, my site does not use PHP and never has had a file with that name. Does anyone know what "mobiquo" is or why someone whould attempt to access "/mobiquo/mobiquo.php"?

Comment: Do you have a forum? Tapatalk? Could be an exploit. Google knows stuff.

Comment: I don't have any of that stuff. It's a totally custom website, not written in PHP and nothing to do with forums. I see it has something to with Tapatalk now, thanks. I'll see what I can find there. I figured it was some sort of potential exploit, but I'm really just curious why a person or bot would continuously request the file over and over on a random website.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is very likely that you have visitors using the **Tapatalk Notifier** Chrome Extension. I don't put a link here because its behaviour seems a bit hazardous, but you can find it on Google .

Apparently it **blindly** tries to `POST "/mobiquo/mobiquo.php"` on **every web page you visit** with Chrome to see if it is a tapatalk compatible forum. When it is the case it can retrieve new messages and show a notification.

We've just had the same kind of log on our Ruby on Rails application. As a result, the visitor was instantly disconnected from our site, because of a Rails protection against AJAX queries which are not issued by the website itself (potential XSS attacks).

Comment: I've audited the source code of the extension, and was like O_o. Fortunately, if the developers do not update the extension, the extension will be removed for [technical reasons](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html#manifest-v1-july2013).